# Join tables related by a composite primary key in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, table, composite-key

I have two tables, one has the geometry and other has attributes. The table with geometry has unique number primary key, and 4 columns `admin1`,`admin2`,`admin3`,`featureid`.

Table two is a csv file and has the same columns mentioned above and their combination forms a composite primary key.

How can I join the two tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS joins cannot use composite keys. You have to create a combined key attribute column if you want to use the QGIS-internal join functionality.

An alternative would be to import the data into Spatialite or PostGIS where you will have more join options including joins on composite keys.

Answer (score 3):

By some 3.x Version QGIS is capable of relations based on composite keys. Under Project > Properties > Relations select the two layers and by clicking [image: the green +] one may define as many field pairs as required for the composite key:

[image]